# Is it possible to modify or Update default claims in JWT token in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We have a requirement where we want to remove or update default claims in JWT token generated by Spring-OAuth2.

For e.g. Spring by default adds clientId, JTI, expires etc in the JWTToken. Is it possible to remove or update any of these from the Token.

Note : I am aware of TokenEnhancer class, but we are not looking for adding new custom claims

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of claims.

**Registered claims:** These are a set of predefined claims which are not mandatory but recommended, to provide a set of useful, interoperable claims. Some of them are: iss (issuer), exp (expiration time), sub (subject), aud (audience), and others.

**Public claims:** These can be defined at will by those using JWTs. But to avoid collisions they should be defined in the IANA JSON Web Token Registry or be defined as a URI that contains a collision resistant namespace.

**Private claims:** These are the custom claims created to share information between parties that agree on using them and are neither registered or public claims.

**Of course, you can modify the reserved claims (for example reducing time). However, overriding names or completely removing expires date and jti will cause security to fail.**